# Swagger2Markup : how to group by tags when using Swagger remote endpoint from test?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox, spring-restdocs

I'm using the great [swagger2markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup) plugin to generate Asciidoc documentation for my REST API as provided by Swagger. I have followed [swagger2markup documentation](http://swagger2markup.github.io/swagger2markup/1.0.1/#_spring_boot_and_springfox) and I am using a Spring MVC integration test to generate markup from my Springfox Swagger endpoint like this (I'm using Maven) :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { AppConfig.class, SwaggerConfig.class })
public class DocumentationIT {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("src/docs/asciidoc/apidoc/generated-snippets");

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void convertSwaggerToAsciiDoc() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/api-docs")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(
                        Swagger2MarkupResultHandler
                                .outputDirectory("src/docs/asciidoc/apidoc")
                                .withExamples("src/docs/asciidoc/apidoc/generated-snippets").build())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Everything is working great and all my paths are in my final documentation, however **paths all appear directly at the root and are not grouped by resources** (i.e. by controllers), so `Method 1` from `Controller 1` will appear at the same level as `Method 2` from `Controller 2`.

My output :

[image]

What I'd like :

[image]

From what I can see, when using generation from a local file like in this [swagger2-markup Maven project template](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup-maven-project-template) you can specify a property to tell swagger2markup to group your paths by tags using the config property `<swagger2markup.pathsGroupedBy>TAGS</swagger2markup.pathsGroupedBy>`, however there does not seem to be such configuration when using `Swagger2MarkupResultHandler` from a test. The only option is `withMarkupLanguage()` but there is no `withPathsGroupedBy()` method...

Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, there is a property of `swagger2markup.pathsGroupedBy` provided by swagger2Markup to specify how the paths should be grouped. However, `Swagger2MarkupResultHandler` do not provide API to support the configuration.

According to [Swagger2Markup API](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/usage_guide.adoc#swagger2markup-properties),

> The properties of Swagger2Markup are defined in the class
>   io.github.swagger2markup.Swagger2MarkupProperties. The properties are
>   considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Java System properties
> 2. Custom properties
> 3. Default properties (included in Swagger2Markup)

it is possible to configure it by using system properties. Therefore, you can set a system property of `swagger2markup.pathsGroupedBy` to `TAGS` in the test.

If you prefer to configure it with Java API, you may extend [Swagger2MarkupResultHandler](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-staticdocs/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/staticdocs/Swagger2MarkupResultHandler.java) and override the `handle` method with the use of [Swagger2MarkupConfigBuilder](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/usage_guide.adoc#configuration) API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the `springfox-staticdocs` plugin does not currently depend on a version of `Swagger2Markup` that supports system properties (it currently depends on `v0.9.2` where the doc you quote seems to be applicable to `v1.0.0`+). 

Your second solution does work great however, and even if I'd rather have that directly in the lib (I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/pull/1498) for that) but this is a fine enough workaround for now, thanks !